# A search div inside header div?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code for css div based layout. I want a search box inside the #header div. But when I add margin or padding to the **#header .search** class, it will add this to height of #header div. Please help me how can I get it correctly. I want the search box at 10px margin-bottom from  where #header div ends.

```
#container {
margin:0px auto;
width:984px;
border-left:#FFFFFF solid 1px;
border-right:#FFFFFF solid 1px;
}

#header {
height:150px;
background: url(./images/header.png) no-repeat;
border-bottom:#FFFFFF solid 1px;
}

#header .search {
margin:0px auto;
text-align:center;
width:620px;
}
```

Comment: It seems very strange that with this CSS code padding or margin on `.search` would influence `#header`. Can you post an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: What is your HTML? Please give an example on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could position the search box absolutely inside the #header

```
#container {
margin:0px auto;
width:984px;
border-left:#FFFFFF solid 1px;
border-right:#FFFFFF solid 1px;
}

#header {
height:150px;
background: url(./images/header.png) no-repeat;
border-bottom:#FFFFFF solid 1px;
position:relative; // parent container
}

#header .search {
margin:0px auto;
text-align:center;
width:620px;
position:absolute;
left:0; bottom:10px;
}
```

This way your search box won't ever affect the parent containers.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fparent/AyyZG/

Comment: alignment with absolute position is hard because the element is out of the flow of the document. A common fix though is to set the "left" property to "50%" and add a *negative* "margin-left" of half the width of the element. e.g. left:50%; margin-left:-100px;

Answer (score 1):

insert a display on both tags, and add a margin-bottom. should work